# Redirect TYPO3 Form to external URL

Tags: forms, url, typo3, typo3-10.x

How do I tell my TYPO3 Form to add a finisher that redirects to a certain URL? I can see the redirect option. But it always gives me an error message because it need a "number". Which don't even get the point of.

Comment: what kind of URL do you want to redirect to? where do you get the error message? what version do you use?

Comment: To a specific Salesforce URL that then can handle the data. I get the error message when i try to add the redirect finisher on the form page. I use 10.4

Answer (score 0):

If you only can redirect to one regular page by it's `uid`, you always can redirect to complexer URLs by creating a special page which is an `Link to external URL` where you can insert any kind of URL, even local URLs with special parameters.

Comment: No because the special parameters that are needed to get the form field data get lost in the redirect.

Comment: Lets say i implement the finisher to redirect to page uid 1. This is my special internal page. On that page i create a redirect to the salesforce url with the special characters {field....etc.}. How does the uid 1 site know to get the special parameter from the typo3 form? Right......it doesnt. So there is no way to carry the form data over basically 3 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no standard way in the TYPO3 backend. We wrote a Form Finisher to do the job. But in our case the external URL is called by a request from the server and the response in given back to the initial request. That way it isn't a redirect. We took the core Redirect Finisher as an example.

The actual code is quite simple (endpointUrl is a parameter defined for the finisher).
//get the form values
$formValues = this->finisherContext->getFormValues();
// get the url parameter from the form settings
$endpoint = $this->parseOption('endpointURL');

```
// cancel all the other finishers because we are the last one
$this->finisherContext->cancel();

// get the post values    
$additionalParams =[
    'form_params'=> $formValues
];

// send the post values to the external URL as POST parameters
$subResponse = $this->requestFactory->request($endpoint, "POST", $additionalParams);

// transfer the response of the request to the response we will throw in a minute; (maybe we could do without that?)



$response = this->responseFactory->createResponse(200)
    ->withHeader('content-type', $subResponse->getHeader('content-type'))
    ->withHeader('Nobit-ExtendedForms', "Redirected from TYPO3 form.")
    ->withBody($subResponse->getBody());

// throw an exception to get the response out, we didn't come up with a way to get that out the normal redirect-handler-way

throw new PropagateResponseException($response, 1477070965);
```